# how to edit some rows of a field based on value from multiple fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE**
added a few combinations of data set to show that `parent_id` is not always [empty string]. this means I cannot simply concatenate `id` into `comment_id`.

---

I have an old table that has data problem like this:

```
id | comment_id | parent_id
===========================
01 | c1         | [empty string]
02 | c2         | [empty string]
03 | c1         | [empty string]
04 | c1         | [empty string]
05 | c1         | c1
06 | c2         | c1
07 | c1         | c2
08 | c1         | c3
```

and this is the expected result:

```
id | comment_id | parent_id
===========================
01 | c1         | [empty string]
02 | c2         | [empty string]
03 | c3         | [empty string]
04 | c4         | [empty string]
05 | c1         | c1
06 | c2         | c1
07 | c1         | c2
08 | c1         | c3
```

I need to change the duplicate `c1` into `c3` (id 03), `c4` (id 04) because there shouldn't be a duplicate of combination between `comment_id` and `parent_id`.

I managed to come up with this sql:

```
select id, comment_id, parent_id, count(*) as mycount
from comments
group by comment_id, parent_id
having count(*) > 1
```

and this is the result:

```
id | comment_id | parent_id | mycount
=====================================
01 | c1         |           | 3
```

so I got the `comment_id` and the number of duplicates but I don't know how to get the `id` that needs to be changed (id 03 and 04) and how to change them.. can anyone help?

Comment: what do you mean? can you elaborate? because that is the data set I currently have..

Comment: unfortunately, the `id` field is an auto-increment primary key.. and the `parent_id` field can contain different value than `[empty string]`. so the number following 'c' is not always the same as `id` value

Comment: sorry. I didn't know that was what you meant. I thought "there shouldn't be a duplicate of combination between comment_id and parent_id" made it clear enough that there could be more combination than [empty string]

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on an auto increment column here.  But if you really want to do a one time update, then use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
UPDATE comments c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM comments
) c2
    ON c2.id = c1.id
SET
    comment_id = CONCAT('c', c2.rn);
```